# Firebase multiple user sign in different browser with same system

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a scenario having multiple types of users in firebase.

`customer`, `admin`, `professor` etc.

Trying to log in a `customer` from one browser and an `admin` from another browser. When I trying to sign using the Firebase function called `firebase_auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password()`.

It automatically clear the previous login and get details for the last logged in user's details.

Is there any solution to login multiple user in firebase within the same browser.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no

The explanation is because the sign in will store a cookie to remember your sign in for your next visit, new tab or refreshing of the page.

What you can do is to open your site in *Incognito Mode* with the same browser. That will give you a completely isolated session that gets wiped of account information when you close the window (you must close all incognito tabs).

- Chrome Incognito Window: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en
- Firefox Private Browsing: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history#w_open-a-link-in-a-new-private-window
- Edge InPrivate window: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026200/windows-browse-inprivate-in-microsoft-edge
- Opera Private Window: https://blogs.opera.com/news/2014/10/how-to-open-private-window-opera-for-computers/
- Safari Private Browsing: https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/safari/browse-in-private-ibrw1069/mac

Answer (score 1):

You can actual use SESSION persistence to keep sessions per tab. So you would have a separate user per session. However, once the tab is closed, the user is lost.

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
```

Learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).